# Join two Tables with no identical Colum names

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I'm a total novice when it comes to SQL query’s but I'm hoping someone could help me?

I have two tables:

Table one has columns:
ClientName
ScheduleName

Table two has columns:
VMName
BackupStatus

Here's my two select statements so far:

```
select * 
from [dbo].[CommCellBkSchedule]
where ClientName LIKE 'KI%'
order by ClientName
```

and

```
select * 
from VMProtectionCoverage (32, '')
where VMName LIKE 'KI%' AND BACKUpSTatus LIKE 'Currently protected'
order by VMName
```

The tables dont have any columns the same but VMName and ClientName have the same details i.e. both server names.

How do I combine the tables to get all the data in one select statement??

i.e. I want the server names, backupstatus and the schedulename?
Any help would be great.

Comment: JOIN doesn't depend on column names. The JOIN .. ON clause requires a full comparison expression, even if some columns happen to have the same name. Even if both tables had a `ClientName` column you'd have to write `ON Table1.ColumnName=Table2.ColumnName`

Comment: `BACKUpSTatus LIKE 'Currently protected'` is equivalent to `BACKUpSTatus = 'Currently protected'`

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text, not images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution using a `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT CS.ClientName, CS.ScheduleName, VC.BackupStatus 
FROM CommCellBkSchedule CS INNER JOIN VMProtectionCoverage(32, '') VC ON CS.ClientName = VC.VMName 
WHERE CS.ClientName LIKE 'KI%' AND VC.BackupStatus LIKE 'Currently protected'
ORDER BY CS.ClientName
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply, looks great but I'm getting: 

**boldMsg 216, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Parameters were not supplied for the function 'VMProtectionCoverage'.**

Embarrassingly I don’t think VMProtectionCoverage is a table.  I'm not entirely sure what it is, I'm hunting through the DB to try and find out.

Comment: @Rob - checkout the update. It looks like a function returning a table.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you join both tables with the common column, in this case, the client name and VMName. If you want one of these tables to be kept without losing data after the join you can use LEFT JOIN mentioned in the tag. Otherwise, the INNER JOIN is fine.

```
SELECT b.VMName,b.BackupStatus,a.ScheduleName
FROM [dbo].[CommCellBkSchedule] a
INNER JOIN [dbo].[VMProtectionCoverage] b
on a.ClientName=b.VMName
where ClientName LIKE 'KI%' AND BACKUpSTatus LIKE 'Currently protected'
order by ClientName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CBS.ClientName, CBS.ScheduleName, VPC.BackupStatus 
FROM CommCellBkSchedule CBS FULL OUTER JOIN VMProtectionCoverage VPC ON CBS.ClientName = VPC.VMName 
WHERE CBS.ClientName LIKE 'KI%' AND VPC.BackupStatus LIKE 'Currently protected'
ORDER BY CBS.ClientName
```

Comment: Please use parameter just after function name ..e.g. VMProtectionCoverage(32, '')

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
select * 
from [dbo].[CommCellBkSchedule] , VMProtectionCoverage (32, '')
where ClientName LIKE 'KI%' MName LIKE 'KI%' AND BACKUpSTatus LIKE 'Currently protected'
order by ClientName,VMName
```